# Number of child elements in Robot Framework / Selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-ide

How to find the total number of elements/tags present under specific tag ?

```
<div id="mainTag class='mainTag'>
     <div id="subMainTag1" class="subMainTag1">
         <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
              <div some inner tags again>
                  <div some inner tags again>
         <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
               <div some inner tags again>
                  <div some inner tags again>
         <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
                <div some inner tags again>
                  <div some inner tags again>
         <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
                <div some inner tags again>
                  <div some inner tags again>
```

I am looking for `div` tags having `id` and `class` `subTag1`.As per snippet provided above, i need to get the count value as `4`.
`verifyXpathCount` does not return the counts.

```
storeXpathCount | //div[@id='mainTag']/div[@id='subMainTag1']/div | count
echo ${count}

storeXpathCount | //div[@id='mainTag']/div[@id='subMainTag1']//div | count
echo ${count}

storeXpathCount | //div[@id='mainTag']/div[@id='subMainTag1']/* | count
echo ${count}
```

All above returns `0`, Nothing returns actual value `4`. Not sure, what i am missing here.

Selenium IDE/web-driver:python , anything is fine.

**ANSWER:**
`storeXpathCount` working fine. I had missed to select frame.
`Get Matching XPath Count` also works fine in Robot Framework.

Comment: Have you tried the robot framework selenium2library keyword [Get matching xpath count](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Matching%20Xpath%20Count)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to [kjhughes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141911/8332700), since he didn't understand you were trying to achieve this using Robot Framework. It wasn't that clear, to his defense.

Using the XPath he provided, you could use the [Xpath Should Match X Times](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Xpath%20Should%20Match%20X%20Times) keyword. Something like this:

```
XPath Should Match X Times    //div[@id='mainTag']/*    4
```

---

If you need to store the retrieved matching count, you can use the quite similar keyword, [Get Matching XPath Count](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Matching%20Xpath%20Count), like this:

```
${count}=    Get Matching XPath Count    //div[@id='mainTag']/*
```

Comment: Thanks, Verv (+1).

Comment: @Verv: Since i need to get the count value, i would go with storeXpathCount. But, it's returning as 0. storeXpathXount  //div[@id='mainTag']/* var , echo ${var}. Tried with //div[@id='mainTag']/div[@id='subTag1'] , but returns 0.

Comment: @Verv: Tried same thing. but returning 0. should i need to select frame, if available ?

Comment: All answers given here are based on the assumption that it's a single page. If more complexities are present, like iframe, windows, etc, please let us know because they do matter.

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
count(//div[@id='mainTag']/*)
```

will return the number of child elements under the `div` element with `id` attribute value of `mainTag`.

Comment: 'count' is which function here ? Is it Selenium API ?

Comment: It's a part of XPath.  Call as you'd evaluate an XPath expression from your language of choice.

Comment: I understand 'count' is builtin function. How do i use it in robot framework ? or any direct selenium APIs to get that ?